# display children on json object

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a php file that returns this json (I've validated it):

```
{"images":{"2":"building.jpg","3":"campus.jpg","4":"grads.jpg","5":"trio.jpg"},"videos":[]}
```

In jquery, how do I return the number of children of 'images'? WhenI use:

```
$.post('php/file.php', {variable: variable}, function(returnedData) {
        console.log(returnedData);
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( returnedData );
        console.log(obj.images.length);

    });
```

I get 'undefined'.

It is the way I'm building the json in php?

```
 $variable= $_POST['variable'];
$imgdir    = '../' . $variable. '/img';
$weeds = array('.', '..'); 
$images = array_diff(scandir($imgdir), $weeds); 
$viddir = '../' . $school . "/vid";
$vids = array_diff(scandir($viddir), $weeds); 
$data = array();
$data['images'] = $images;
$data['videos'] = $vids;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Try obj['images'].length  Also, what does console.log(obj) show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `obj.images` is not `Array`, you can get `length` like so

```js
var returnedData = {"images":{"2":"building.jpg","3":"campus.jpg","4":"grads.jpg","5":"trio.jpg"},"videos":[]};

console.log(Object.keys(returnedData.images).length);
```

> [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties

or you can use `for..in`, like so

```js
 var returnedData = {"images":{"2":"building.jpg","3":"campus.jpg","4":"grads.jpg","5":"trio.jpg"},"videos":[]};

var count = 0;
for (var i in returnedData.images) {
  if (returnedData.images.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
     count += 1;  
  }
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using $.getJSON():

```
$.getJSON('php/file.php', {variable: variable}, function(returnedData) {
    console.log(returnedData);
    console.log(Object.keys(returnedData.images).length);
});
```